# PHP header in if statement not redirecting user

Tags: php, database, header

I am currently working on a login page on which I want the user to be redirected to another page if a Boolean read from the database is set to true.
However, the header() in this if statement never redirects the user properly.

here is a sample of my code:

```
<?php
session_start();
include_once 'php/dbconnect.php';
//check if form is submitted
if (isset($_POST['login'])) {
    $gebruikersnaam = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['username']);
    $password = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['password']);
    $result = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM users WHERE username = '" . $gebruikersnaam. "' and password = '" . md5($password) . "'");
    if ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
        $_SESSION['usr_id'] = $row['id'];
      if($row['initialised'] == true)
      {
        header("Location: dashboard.php");
        exit();
      }
      else{
        $_SESSION['usr_name'] = $row['username'];
        $_SESSION['usr_company'] = $row['companyname'];
        header("Location: starter-page.php");
        exit();
      }
      } else {
        $errormsg = "Incorrect Email or Password!"; 
    }
}
?>
```

If I put the if condition on false. The second header with "location: strater-page.php" will redirect to the correct page.

I do not have any unnecessary whitespace.

Putting:

```
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
```

In the code doesn't show anything.
I am not outputting anything before the header...
Am I missing something?

Comment: Have you tried to verify you are in correct IF statement branch? (try to call echo 'foo'; and comment out redirection) If you are, try to verify if you've reached correct script - onto very first lines after <?php of dashboard.php script, put something like echo 'This is dashboard.php'; exit();. After reach correct file, you can switch error_reporting of this file on and maybe you'll see something. I think we have really few information about your problem. Please try to get know something more.

Comment: You know, it could be caused by many things. I've tried to simulate your algorithm and it's working for me. Try to explore more.

Comment: Please send  your full code with database(user table). I ill give solution.

Comment: Wow ok, it turns out i had a small check in database.php which would redirect me back to login.php. I feel kind of stupid right now. Thanks anyway

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try redirect using script

```
<?php
if($row['initialised'] == true)
  {
  echo ("<SCRIPT LANGUAGE='JavaScript'>
  window.location.href='dashboard.php';
 </SCRIPT>");
}
?>
```

Comment: Doesn't solve it i'm afraid. Thank you for your fast response though.

Comment: my js console is empty. And my php_error_log also doesn't output anything correlating to this.

Comment: no, the other guy helped me, but i don't know how to give him credit because he commented on my question. So i give it to you, lol.